# for loop ignores nested if Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using phone number to let user signup and now when they sign out and wanna sign in again i have same interface as Uber so they've to verify their phone to login , but my code won't work it just loads one and only one user, loops through whole db to last user instead of if() returning true it ignores and iterates through whole db

```
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        //user.getUserPhone().matches(mobileNumber)
                        String ph = user.getUserPhone();

                        boolean matched = ph.contentEquals(mobileNumber);
                        if (!matched) {
                            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", mobileNumber);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
```

[image: See this]

[image: Wrong output]

Comment: Your description is a little unclear, but I would mention that starting an `Activity` is an asynchronous operation. That is, your `for` loop is not going to pause when you call `startActivity()`.

Comment: i've tried the if otherway too, i mean if (matched) launch activity else SignInwithPhoneAuth

Comment: so should i use finish there? or call another function to launch my activity?

Comment: No, you'll have to rethink your approach. Do you mean to start `HomeActivity` multiple times, once for each matched user? Or are you just trying to pass all of them to `HomeActivity` at once?

Comment: i'm matching phone number of the user with the user's saved on db if that number is there, the app should launch homeActivity otherwise it should send the user to another method which sends to profileActivity where user provides name and stuff for first time

Comment: phoneNumber is used as key instead of Uid so,it should match and it does matches one and only one user

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I follow. Let me make sure: you have a list of users in your database. You're looping over all of them to check if one user matches. If so, then go to `HomeActivity`. If none of them match, then go to `ProfileActivity`.

Comment: Yup that's what i'm trying...I've only three user right now and in debugging it shows me all of them one by one while inside the loop...one returns true but it ignores and goes to the next db child

Comment: Then you need to move the `if-else` out of the `for` loop, to after it. Declare `boolean matched = false;` and `String ph = null;` before the loop, set them the same way you are now inside the loop, and then do the `if-else` after it.

Comment: oh gotcha, lemme try i have a feeling that'll work

Comment: @MikeM. it didn't work, see pictures

Comment: If your breakpoint is right on that line, `matched` will still show `false`, because that line hasn't executed yet. Check it after that.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working. Please don't feel obligated to accept an answer if it didn't solve your issue. Cheers!

Comment: Navylover one's was close to solution so...had to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Acheived it by calling a function inside if else and then using break;

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if (!matched) {
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
    break; //add this to exit loop
}
```

Comment: it always go to not matched so, i don't think that'd help but lemme try

Answer (score 0):

You need exit from the whole for loop after check the condition in

```
 if (!matched) {
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

   // return;

    } else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, 
       HomeActivity.class);
       user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
       intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", mobileNumber);
       startActivity(intent);
     //  return;
                    }
```

user return  keyword  place where you want do some execution after  true matched 
both numbers.